# Unable to Access Key-Value Pair Twitter API User Timeline

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I am getting the following `undefined index` error when I try to access the `screen_name` key value pair from Twitter API 1.1 User Timeline `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json`

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: screen_name
>
> Filename: controllers/search.php
>
> Line Number: 98

I can see the screen_name key when I print_r(); the associative array that stores the results:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [created_at] => Tue Mar 19 21:55:31 +0000 2013
>   [id] => 3.141330578148E+17 [id_str] => 314133057814798336 [text] =>
>   Win a 4-Pack of tickets to the @VanAutoShow March 26-31 via @604Now –
>   http://t.co/2G0pyNNgLl RT to Enter! [source] => Twitter for Mac
>   [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str]
>   => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => Array ( [id] => 128700677
>   [id_str] => 128700677 [name] => Bernard Poon [screen_name] =>
>   StackOverflow [location] => Vancouver, BC [description] => Code Monkey
>   that calls Vancouver home. Loves Apple products and newbie
>   photographer. [url] => http://t.co/wlxhr5tpes [entities] => Array (
>   [url] => Array ( [urls] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] =>
>   http://t.co/wlxhr5tpes [expanded_url] => http://ceciliaandbernard.com
>   [display_url] => ceciliaandbernard.com [indices] => Array ( [0] => 0
>   [1](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json) => 22 ) ) ) ) [description] => Array ( [urls] => Array ( ) ) )
>   [protected] => [followers_count] => 157 [friends_count] => 13
>   [listed_count] => 4 [created_at] => Thu Apr 01 23:16:57 +0000 2010
>   [favourites_count] => 0 [utc_offset] =>

I am able to access the screen_name key value pair if I use the [Users Show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) TWitter API 1.1 resource with no errors. However, when I use the [User Timeline](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json) Twitter API 1.1 resource, I get the above `undefined index` error. Below is a code snippet of the function I'm using to access both of these resources with different results:

```
function does_user_exist($r) 
{
    // convert to associative array
    // inorder to search for keys
    $a = json_decode($r, true);         

    echo "Screen Name: " . $a['screen_name'];       
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its inside another array. try the following code

```
echo "Screen Name: " . $a[0]['screen_name'];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. I thought so but I'm still getting this `undefined index` error after changing it to `$a[0]['screen_name'];`. The screen name I am using is correct. Not sure why I'm still getting this error

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. This worked! `echo "Screen Name: " . $a[0]['user']['screen_name'];`